# Regex to find Upper case character at beginning of each word in a field

Tags: regex

I created  a function that will compare a field against a regex and return 0 if it doesn't match the patter and 1 if it does.  I've already created the class so I could  create a UDF for the pattern matching.

```
function(expression,rexex) //If it matches it
```

I have been researching regex in SQL server for a bit this weekend and am at a bit of a crossroad.

I basically need to have the following pattern with 1 passing and 0 failing.  Basically I want the first letter of every word do be capitalized:

```
the dog is bad - 0
The Dog Is Bad - 1
```

I'm ashamed to say that it's taken me all day just to figure out how to idenfity the first letter of each work and see if it's capital.

Here is what I have so far.

```
[\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]
```

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes letters only, and only one space per word:

```
^((?:\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b) {0,1})+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eACjx3Sxvh2DZFWG)

Free spaced:

```
^              //Start of line
(              //(Capture)
   (?:         //(Non-capture)
       \b      //      Followed by word boundary
       [A-Z]   //      Followed by a capital letter
       [a-z]*  //      Followed by zero or more lowercase letters
       \b      //      Followed by word boundary
   ) {0,1}     //      Followed by either no space, or one space
)+             //   One or more times
$              //End of line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!)` to validate the line/sentence:

```
/(?!.*?\b[a-z].*?\b)^.*?$/gm
```

This will not pass on any string or line which has a word that begins with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I don't understand this, and I would like to. It doesn't work in Debuggex (not in any flavor: https://www.debuggex.com/r/QA3oLr_Jh1Zou0ih), but it does work in  RegexBuddy.

Comment: On Debuggex, change the flavor to something like Python and add the `m` flag. More info on Lookaheads here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Start of match (`^`) followed by one or more groups (`(...)+`) of a capital letter (`[A-Z]`) followed by zero or more word characters (`\w*`) followed by one or more spaces, or the end (`(\s+|$)`).

```
/^([A-Z]\w*(\s+|$))+/
```

[image: regex]

Comment: How'd you create the image?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you want to be unicode compatible, I'd do:

```
(?:^|\s+)(\p{lu}\p{Ll}*)
```